# python django как сделать маршруты и ssl

Tags: python, django, flask, веб-сервер

В django перешел из Flask, там был удобный url диспетчер.
Декоратор с маршрутом и функция. А как такое сделать в django?
И как в django поставить SSL? (сертификаты есть)

Задача очень простая, домашний веб сервер с поддержкой SSL. т.е. сервер не нагруженный и не большой. На django перешел потому, что встроенный во flask сервер - плохой. А разбираться с wsgi смысла нет для текущей задачи.

Comment: И в документации Django, и в документации Flask написано, что использовать встроенный сервер для чего-то кроме разработки — категорически нельзя, он не предназначен для реальной работы

Comment: @andreymal задача слишком мала, чтобы городить сторонние серверы

Comment: И поддержка SSL в Django, кажется, отстутсвует по той же причине — потому что нужно использовать сторонний сервер с поддержкой всего чего надо. (Где-то даже была дискуссия о том, чтобы полностью удалить встроенный сервер из Django, но, видимо, не решились)

Comment: @andreymal во Flask сервер поддерживает SSL. Но как-то странно работает, он ssl не может через роутер вывести в сеть. хотя все порты прокинуты и в локальной тоже все работает. но как только соединение ssl даже если на 80 порту то все... из глобальной не работает. хотя если отключить ssl то все ок на любом порту.

Comment: SSL/HTTPS должен быть не на 80, а на 443 порту. А выставлять встроенный сервер в сеть — вдвойне плохая идея, взломает любой мимо прогуливающийся хакер